# Is there any Powershell script which gives us ACL permissions from all the containers in Storage account Gen 2

Tags: containers, azure-powershell, acl, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

We have multiple subscriptions with lots of resource groups and each RG contains Gen 2 storage account. We need to export ACL permissions from all the containers in each storage account i.e. Gen2. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: We need to export all the container ACL permissions from all the resource groups from subscription. Seems Azure PowerShell should be good idea for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to export ACL permissions from all the containers in each storage account i.e. Gen2. Any suggestions?

You can use the below command to export the ACL permissions from all containers in storage accounts.

**Command:**

```
Connect-AzAccount
 
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount 

$results = foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
    $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context
    foreach ($container in $containers) {
        $filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem $container.Name
        $s = $storageAccount.storageaccountname
        $r = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
        $filesystemname = $container.Name
        $aclpermission = $filesystem.ACL.Permissions -join ","
        $aclaccesscontroltype=$filesystem.ACL.AccessControlType -join ","

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            StorageAccountName = $s
            ResourceGroupName = $r 
            ContainerName = $filesystemname
            ACLpermission = $aclpermission
            ACLaccesscontroltype=$aclaccesscontroltype
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above script gets the all storageaccounts and containers it checks and fetch the ACL permissions and access controltype from the gen2 accounts.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I am getting error while using above script.
Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item : Service request failed.
Status: 400 (This operation is only supported on a hierarchical namespace account.)
ErrorCode: HierarchicalNamespaceNotEnabled

Comment: Hi @user1628 the above error will get because some of your storage account are not enabled hierarchical namespace.

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan - Can I get ACL permissions of container's sub folders as well?